# How to prove $2a^4+2b^4 \geq c^2(2a^2+2b^2-c^2)$ for any positive $a$, $b$ and $c$?

Tags: inequality, sums-of-squares

How to prove $2a^4+2b^4 \geq c^2(2a^2+2b^2-c^2)$ for $a,b,c>0$?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

We can assume $c^2 \le 2(a^2 + b^2)$, otherwise, we've nothing to prove.

Comment: I have a proof, i can show it to you once you show your attempt

Comment: Also, you might also consider using $AM-GM$: $$2a^4+\frac{c^4}{2}\geqslant 2c^2a^2$$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2a^4+2b^4 \geqslant c^2(2a^2+2b^2-c^2) \iff (a^2-b^2)^2+(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2\geqslant 0$$